# Difference between include in .h file and .c file

Tags: c++, header, include

What is the difference between doing a `#include` in a `.h` file and in a `.c` file?

For example, I have the file `a.h` and `a.c` which have the `class A`. I use `class A` in `class B` (`b.h`, `b.c`). What is the difference between doing an include:

```
#include "a.h"
```

in `b.h` vs `b.c`?

Comment: @karlphillip: even if you misunderstood, you can perfectly include a `.c` file. You can even include a `.xls` file. It's likely your compilation (not preprocessing) will fail, but you can still include it.

Comment: If you have `#include "a.h"` inside `b.h`, then every compilation that uses `b.h` also has to include `a.h`.  If you can avoid that with forward declarations, other people will be happier.  That said, if `b.h` must know about the internals of `a.h`, don't hesitate to include it, but avoid the dependency and connectivity if you can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, the class definition is typically in your .h file, and the implementation is in your .c(pp) file.

One advantage of doing `#include "a.h"` in your b.c file, rather than in your b.h file, is that whenever a.h changes, not only b.c but also any other file that includes b.h will have be recompiled.

Also, you're kind of unnecessary exposing implementation details of B to anyone using b.h. The idea is that b.h should not contain additional info that is of no interest to someone using class B (not because it's secret, but because people don't care and you don't want to bother them with it).

There's no need to force anyone including b.h, to indirectly include a dozen of other .h files as well (because they're #included in b.h), just because you happen to use that stuff in b.c. Avoid clutter.

**So if possible, it's best to `#include "a.h"` in b.c !**

But this is not always possible. If you're just using A inside b.c, and there are no references to A in b.h, then it's OK. Also, if b.h only contains pointers to A (i.e. as members, function arguments or return values) but no 'type dependent' references, you could also put just this in b.h:

```
class A;
```

And still keep `#include "a.h"` in your b.c. But if there are more references or dependencies on a.h, that anyone including b.h really couldn't do without, then `#include "a.h"` should go in b.h

Answer (score 2):

There is No difference in including a header file in `.h` or `.c` file.
The contents of the included file are just copy pasted in to the file in which you include it.

Comment: For code expanding this is true, but as headers are often reused, including another header has significant repercussions (compile-time, pulling in names in the global namespace, ...)

Comment: I have a case where including a .h file in .c file instead of a .h reduced compilation time. The actual class details are too complex to write here, since I myself am working on a small part. So just conceptually/point of view of a compiler, wondering how this changes the compilation time?

Comment: The above comment has been answered. Thank you for your answer also.

Answer (score 2):

If you put the include directive in your header file, other files that include that header file will also get the included header.

foo.h:

```
#include "dependency.h"
```

bar.h:

```
#include "foo.h"
```

In this case, bar.h has both foo.h and dependency.h.

Answer (score 0):

`#include "a.h"` expands to the contents of `a.h`.

If `#include "a.h"` is placed in `b.h`, then `a.h` will be copied into `b.h` during compilation.

If `#include "a.h"` is placed in `b.c`, then `a.h` will be copied into `b.c` during compilation instead.

Answer (score 0):

.h files put at top of .c or .h files before compile

but .c files compile separately then link to getter to make executable file

Answer (score 0):

You can include `.c` files - but by convention you do not.

`.h` files are for declarations - i.e. the `.c` file is the definition and the this `.h` file is going to do this. It is like the `.h` file is the contents of the cook book, and the `.c` file is the actual recipes.